# Query based on index value or value in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame from which I computed the mean scores of students. Student scores are stored in `data` as below:

```
   name score
 0 John   90
 1 Mary   87
 2 John  100
 3 Suzie  90
 4 Mary   88
```

By using `meanscore = data.groupby("name").mean()`
I obtain 

         `score
  name
  John   95
  Mary   87.5
  Suzie  90`

I would like to query, for instance, `meanscore['score'][meanscore['name'] == 'John']` This line yields `KeyError: 'name'`

I know my way of doing it is not nice, as I can actually find out the meanscore of John by using `mean['score'][0]`.

My question is: is there a way to find the corresponding index value of each name (e.g. [0] for John, [1] for Mary and [2] for Suzie) in my query? Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [11]: meanscore
Out[11]:
       score
name
John    95.0
Mary    87.5
Suzie   90.0

In [12]: meanscore.loc["John", "score"]
Out[12]: 95.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
meanscore['score']['John']
```

Example:

```
>>> df
    name  score
0   John     90
1   Mary     87
2   John    100
3  Suzie     90
4   Mary     88

>>> meanscore = df.groupby('name').mean()
>>> meanscore
       score
name
John    95.0
Mary    87.5
Suzie   90.0
>>> meanscore['score']['John']
95.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer is also correct and elegant.

Comment: Cheers, mate! Happy coding to you :-)